# Failed to transform the goal pose from map to map frame

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to run the RRT exploration with the turtlebot3 using the following setting:
[image: image description]

But while running the RRT exploration algorithm. I encountered such issue:
[image: image description]

The transformation stops at a certain time and keep popping out request time error.
Any clue how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380506/failed-to-transform-the-goal-pose-from-map-to-map-frame/) by [hikashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/76187/hikashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hassan Iqbal](https://answers.ros.org/users/77342/hassan-iqbal/) on 2021-07-07**:
I don't have a solution. Wanted to ask how were you able to catkin_make rrt_exploration package in ROS Melodic? I am getting cmake errors and have been trying to manually resolve but it seems a daunting task.

**Comment by [hikashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/76187/hikashi/) on 2021-07-07**:
I reuse most of the code in the RRT_package, the most difficult would be setting up the turtlebot to run with RRT.
catkin_make should not be an issue, I think the mapping of the topic is a tedious task.
I do not have details of the catkin_error, so I cant really comment much about the problem you are facing.

Anyway, I attached the github link that I managed to solve the issue,
https://github.com/hikashi/multi-robot-rrt-exploration-melodic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem turns out to be move_base parameter issue.

I have resolved the problem by changing the costmap and remap some of the topic required.
Working solution can be found in
https://github.com/hikashi/multi-robot-rrt-exploration-melodichttps://github.com/hikashi/multi-robot-rrt-exploration-melodic

---

Originally posted by [hikashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/76187/hikashi/) with karma: 36 on 2021-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aryaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/108152/aryaman/) on 2022-06-13**:
hey, what issue was there with the move_base parameters. I am also trying to run rrt exploration with 2 real robots(not turtlebots) and facing the same issue

**Comment by [hikashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/76187/hikashi/) on 2022-06-21**:
Hi Aryaman, it has been some time since I encountered this issue.
If I recall correctly, I was changing the frequency to a lower number and using a local map instead of a merged map.
Apparently, this is an issue with simulation using Gazebo rather than robot implementation.

As mentioned in my post, you are free to check the attached GitHub link as I have updated the working solution regarding this issue,

**Comment by [aryaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/108152/aryaman/) on 2022-06-21**:
Thank you for your reply. I had one more doubt. When I am using multirobot_map_merge package with known_init_position parameter set as false (because I can't know initial position of real robots), the merged map is taking only one robot's map and not othes', Its producing the same map as one of the robots. Do you know what can be the problem?

Also, is there any way where I can get to know initial positions of real robots so that I can use multirobot_map_merge with known_init_position as true?

**Comment by [aryaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/108152/aryaman/) on 2022-06-25**:
Can you please specify which frequency parameters did you change? when I am trying to change the frequency, it's not making any difference. Also, what do you mean by "using a local map instead of a merged map"?